# Regression Terminology

Tags: regression, terminology

This is a very basic question, but I haven't been able to get an answer with my google-fu.

In the following sentences:

> We regress W on Z
>
> We performed a regression of W on Z

I'm unsure what **of** and **on** denote. Do I read that as:

$W \tilde{} \alpha + \beta Z + \epsilon $

or

$Z \tilde{} \alpha + \beta W + \epsilon $

Comment: @Glen_b are you putting the dependent variable on the right hand side? Typo or maybe I'm confused:)?

Comment: @Karl Uh, yes exactly, that's a typo. Try again! ... Both phrases have W on the *left* (dependent variable, response variable, y-variable) and Z on the *right* (independent variable, predictor variable, x-variable). [I realize this pretty much duplicates the answer, but I wanted to explicitly confirm that this is the case.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "regression of W on Z" means you're predicting W from Z. Using your equations, this corresponds to the first one, namely $W=\alpha+\beta Z+\epsilon$